# Is using both “What has just happened?” and “What has been just happened?” fine?

Tags: participles, transitivity

> What has just happened?

> What has been just happened?

The first one is right, but my friend told me that we can't use “has been [...] happened” because it has two past participles, which is ungrammatical.

Comment: Well, you **can** have a sentence "What has just *been done*?" so your friend is not entirely right. Perhaps someone will chime in with **why** one of your sentences is correct and the other is not.

Answer (score 5):

As Andrew has said, it is perfectly possible to have two past participles in a passive clause. What is not possible is to make a passive clause with an intransitive verb such as *happen*. That is why ‘What has been just happened?’ is ungrammatical.